# Android save multiple images

Tags: bitmap, android-imageview

My project has more than 100 images in drawable & I would like to save a copy of these images to phone gallery by click on a button. I'm using below code to save image.  Each time I click the button to save the image it save only one image, if I click the second button for the second image it replaced the first saved one. Is there any solution for this problem, thanks.

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.guest_1);

//First we save image to cache
cachePath = getExternalCacheDir() + "/image.jpg";

java.io.File pictureFile = new java.io.File(cachePath);

try {
java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new                 java.io.FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
fos.close();
showMessage("image saved");
} catch (Exception e) {
showMessage(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Please edit the code, formatted, into your question, not as a comment, if you expect anyone to read it.

Comment: sure, thanks brother